# Is it possible, via GPO or other method, to turn Internet Explorer's intranet compatibility mode OFF across a domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, windows-registry

Our school's VLE has a few problems when running in IE8/IE9's Compatibility View. Mainly it causes difficulties with uploading files.

This problem is easily remedied by un-ticking the `Display intranet sites in Compatibility View` option from Internet Explorer's `Compatibility View` options.

[image: Compatibility View options]

However, I'm unable to find a way of doing this *en masse*. I can't find anything regarding this in GPO - would a registry hack or similar do the trick?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the group policy you want is User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Compatibility View\ intranetcompatabilitymode set to disabled